# Strategy for adding registry keys for an application that may not yet be installed?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In my wix installer I want to add registry keys to the following key path

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Edge\NativeMessagingHosts
```

This path exists if the user has installed Microsoft Edge Chromium.

I can conditionally add keys if this path exists, however how am I supposed to deal with the case where after the user installs my application they install Edge Chromium?

Will there be any issue if my installer simply creates this path first?

Comment: Is this a per user or per machine install?

Comment: This is a per user install.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer can only be resolved by testing the interaction with Chromium Edge.  Create a VM and snapshot it before and after installing Chromium Edge.  Test your installer using both snapshots and see if the behavior is the same.

Generally I would block the installation of your product if it requires another product.  Even if the order of operations don't matter there is still the scenario where your product is installed and Edge isn't.  This might not be a big deal if it's an optional feature but if it's the core feature of your product then someone might think your application is broken.  This is why we would block the install and say it require another product.